# what kind of shower handle do i need for this type of rough valve? I don't know name of old handle

Tags: shower

[image][image: Valve]

I am a first time DIY on a shower handle.  I removed our old shower handle it does not have a brand name on it.  The way it operates is that you pull knob out to turn water on.  I have tried a trim kit for a delta and a moen and neither seem to work with this type of valve.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange. A couple more pictures (especially close-ups) would be helpful. If you aren't allowed to post the pictures because of your low reputation, just post the URLs and someone will be along to edit them in.

Comment: Since the rough plumbing has been exposed, now would be the time to completely replace the shower valve. The one you have is most likely not up to code since it appears to completely lack any scald protection. Newer valves have a limit to how far you can turn the knob, so the water cannot get too hot. The higher end ones also balance the water pressure, and prevent you from getting a cold or hot blast of water when someone else uses the plumbing. With it in place, someone can flush the toilet while you are taking a shower, and you would barely notice a difference in the water temperature.

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely a Moen. It has a "pull out dial" handle or (more specifically) Moen 96797  Chateau One-Handle Tub and Shower Knob; and I think the cartridge is 1225B.

[image]

Here's a video about [replacing the cartridge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKLBqKk-j50) (it shows exactly the save valve) and in the beginning you can see the tear drop shaped handle.